# Could not connect to SQL Server but Excel and ODBC config can

Tags: c#, excel, sql-server-2008, ado.net, sql-server-2012

I have a C# program to connect to SQL Server. It works fine at the test computer with SQL Server 2012 but does not work on the production environment with 2008. At the production environment, it reports exception as such,

> Unhandled Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or in
>   stance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Th
>   e server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is c
>   orrect and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider:
>    Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) --
>   -> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied

here is my connection code,

```
connStrSql = "Server=" + sqlserver + "; Database=" + sqldb + "; Trusted_Connection=True";
SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connStrSql)
sqlConn.Open();
```

The target platform is x86 and target framework is 4.5. The funny thing is that Excel and ODBC config can connect to the database without complain. Does C# program use different way connecting to SQL Server? How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Are you connecting try to connection to SQL Server remotely?

Comment: yes, should I try different network library like tcp instead of the default named pipe?

Comment: OK. Is Excel remote, or local, to the SQL Server?

Comment: Excel is remote too. Excel and my program are in the same computer but sqlserver is at another server.

Comment: There are different client protocols available to use to connection to  SQL Server. These can be enabled/disabled. Do you know what client protocols the production SQL Server has enabled? View can check this via the Sql Server Configuration Manager.

Answer (score 3):

There are many possible reasons why you can not connect to an SQL Server database. [This](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/) is a great trouble shooting guide to help you solve the above error.

Briefly:

1. Is the SQL Server services running?
2. Has the SQL Server TCP/IP settings been configured?
3. Does the firewall settings allow SQL Server through?
4. Has SQL Server itself been configured allow remote connections?

Other things to consider

1. Is the value of `sqlserver` correct?
2. Has the client protocol you are using to connection to SQL Server, such as `Named Pipes`, been enabled?

Comment: I believe the sqlsever is running because I can use Excel at the production sever to get data from that sqlserver. The most confusing part is that Excel works perfectly at the situation but my program doesn't. If Excel works, doesn't it means that sqlserver is configured correctly for remote connection and why shouldn't my program.

Answer (score 2):

One of the most common reasons for a remote connection being refused in newer versions of SQL Server is the SQL Browser is not turned on. It is off by default after an install. Another common reason is you don't have the particular protocol (in this case net pipes) turned on, but I would check the SQL Browser first, as it is probably turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Might be firewall/security restriction in production - Try running against a local SQL2008 db because I just ran the code against SQL2008 and it does work with a correct sqlserver and sqldb parameter and change the line below ( missing ; )

SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connStrSql);

Answer (score 0):

Try this for SQL Server connection:

Attach a database file on connect to a local SQL Server Express instance

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=C:\MyFolder\MyDataFile.mdf;Database=dbname;
Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

Attach a database file, located in the data directory, on connect to a local SQL Server Express instance

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|mydbfile.mdf;Database=dbname;
Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

Try this Excel Connection string

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;
Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1";
```

If any other problem regarding connection string, refer this site

MS-Excel: http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/

MS SQL Server: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Thanks,
NB